# How to analyze plot from libsvm grid-search

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to learn to use  libsvm, I have used some defalut training sets to generate the plots by grid-search and obtained a plot below.

I want to know,

- What type of plot is this,
- What does it really tells us,
- How to understand and analyze this plot.

  Thanks in advance.

[image: Libsvm grid-search]

Answer (score 1):

Grid search performs a search in two parameters of your svm: c and gamma.

These two parameters are displayed in logarithmic axes x and y in this graph. The lines indicate which areas the grid search has been.

The colours of the lines are like "hight-lines" on a geographical map. They indicate the quality of the solutions found there and display the graphical bounds of the searched space in a graph.

Remember how grid search works:

> The initial grid is worked on with 2-fold CV to determine the values
>   of the parameter pairs for the selected type of evaluation (e.g.,
>   accuracy). The best point in the grid is then taken and a 10-fold CV
>   is performed with the adjacent parameter pairs. If a better pair is
>   found, then this will act as new center and another 10-fold CV will be
>   performed (kind of hill-climbing). This process is repeated until no
>   better pair is found or the best pair is on the border of the grid. In
>   case the best pair is on the border, one can let GridSearch
>   automatically extend the grid and continue the search. -- [source](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/gridSearch/index.html)

If I am correct, the lines indicate where the deeper search is performed.

But just to double check, which software did you use to generate this? Matlab or weka?

Comment: I was using `grid.py` from libsvm package